# My App's cache and data are too big

Tags: android, performance, caching

I have an Android app that parses data from a website using Jsoup library, 
but my problem is that after browsing through the app for some time the cache gets bigger and bigger and after a couple of days or so of usage when the cache is too big (**reaches up to 200mb!**) the app will start to lag and will end up throwing OutOfMemory exceptions.

I have used LeakCanary library and It detected some leaks but they were only a few KBs, also the only images I use in my app are small profile pictures I load with Picasso library and I doubt they are the one causing this mayhem.

If anyone can help I will really appreciate it thanks!
Here are some pictures below if they can help in anything.

The app's data and cache size
[image: The app's data and cache size]

Home screen
[image: Home screen]

Comment: Cache doesn't cause OOM exceptions.  Cache is disk space.  OOM is from RAM.

Comment: @GabeSechan what could be then? Im really confused about this

Answer (score 1):

You can limit Picasso cache size by writing this code in onCreate of Application class

```
    private static final long IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100MB

    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE));
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

Picasso uses automatic caching to save loading time.
You can also clear picasso cache by adding this class to the com.squareup.picasso package.

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

public class PicassoTools {

public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
        p.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Because cache has package visibility, this util class can clear the cache for you. You just have to call it:

```
PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

Comment: But does Picasso cache the same images again and again?

Comment: I am not sure about this but it does not cache the same image again and again.

Comment: then I think this might not be the problem that I’m facing because even if all the images in the app are cached it won’t reach even 100mb

Comment: Picasso caches the image for single session meaning if it downloads image one time it will not download again the same image when the app is running. But it will download the same image again if you restart the app.